# How to Authenticate a user based on email id and password in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, email, authentication

I just wanted to authenticate a user based on the email id and the password.

For ex: if he enters the username as "sample@gmail.com" and password as "password". I need to authenticate the above details. Is it possible. I just wanted to authenticate the user and not to send a mail. I came to know that, if we try to send a mail with wrong password, we get exception which we can catch and process it accordingly.

But is there any we can authenticate without sending a mail.

Thanks in advance
Jonathon

Answer (score 1):

You may certainly like yo check [How to: Implement Simple Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)